# How to render a smooth timelapse from 30FPS video?

Tags: time-lapse

So here's my problem: I make timelapses from my cycling rides and the results are [extremely shaky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qW0ghrIW1io) because the software picks frames linearly and sometimes I turn the handlebar or tilt the bike slightly, and the view is completely different to what it was the previous frame. This makes the video rather annoying to watch

So, I was wondering if there are some smarter algos out there that can 'smooth out' timelapses -- not in the *motion blur* sense (I suppose you can just average out the frames) but in terms of picking the right frames based on the delta changes between significant objects.

If there's some alternative approach to this, I'd be interested, too.

Answer (score 1):

I ain't sure if this will work but *better than nothing!*

Here two of my approaches to this problem:

1. **Warp Stabilization**

   Software such as Mocha, AE and many others have **Warp Stabilization**. What is means is that it can automatically stabilize the clip based on the frames and it somewhat relates to Machine Learning approach to Big Data.
2. **Converting to 24fps**

   You can open in in a video editor and manually delete clips based on your own human ability to judge by looking at the previous and next frame. As we know our eyes can think 24fps as a smooth video clip, you may try this manual fix technique by deleting at 3-5 frames per second of your video!

Giving an opinion based answer, I think warp stabilization would render quite great results.

Comment: > "our eyes can think 24fps as a smooth video clip" — nope, they can't. well, at least while the person is not intoxicated. the minimum fps is somewhere around 40..50, depends on person, but never as low as 24.

Comment: also, simple decimation of frames would make motion speed non-smooth and it will add more salt to the injury. even replacing frame with a copy of previous frame or a blend of adjacent frames would be better than simply removing it.

Comment: @SargeBorsch may you please mention some source? FPS in a video game is different from fps in video clips. Apple.com says: [24fps is also considered as the worldwide standard for movie theater film projectors.](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=D%26section=3%26tasks=true)
You may further refer here: [Reddit: Movies have 24fps and still feel extremely smooth whereas games under 30fps are literally unplayable](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3m80tp/eli5_movies_have_24fps_and_still_feel_extremely/)

Comment: The frame rate in movie theatres is actually doubled, by displaying each frame twice. There are two different things going on there: persistence of vision allows most motion at 24fps to look smooth–though not really fast pans, ask any cinematographer–but our ability to perceive flickering is much higher, meaning that we can detect that a 24 Hz strobe is flickering, rather than perceive it as a steady source. So cinema projectors have a 48hz frame rate, but every frame is doubled, or in the case of older hand-drawn animation, quadrupled.

Comment: @InderdeepB. it's obviously visible, why need a source? yes, most movies aren't close to being smooth, that is a sad fact of life. I didn't mention games at all; 40 or 50 fps would be totally unacceptable for games.

Comment: @SargeBorsch it was an opinion based question. People across stackexchange always criticized opinion based answers. In my opinion, warp stabilization was the best thing one could do. However, depleting frames was a workaround for the footage. And in terms of fps, neither among my software (Nuke, AE & Blender) experienced any problem in the past doing things that were somewhat similar deleting frames.